# Symfony 4 - JSON authentication not working

Tags: php, json, symfony, authentication

I am trying to build a json authentication mechanism in Symfony basing on this docs:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/json_login_setup.html

Here is my security.yaml

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
providers:
    user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: username
firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      anonymous: ~
      json_login:
        check_path: login
      provider: user_provider
      logout:
        path: logout
```

Here is my method login in my security controller

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    ...
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function login()
    {
        return new Response('Lala');
    }
    ...
}
```

And here is my login form

```
<form class="form" id="login-nav">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="username">Login</label>
    <input id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Login" required
           name="_username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Hasło" required
           name="_password">
    <div class="help-block text-right">
        <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <a id="login-submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</a>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
</div>
```

And below you can see my AJAX request which I am sending to controller

```
$('#login-submit').click(function() {
    let username = $('#username').val();
    let password = $('#password').val();
    let data = JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password});
    $.ajax({
        url: '/login',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (data, status) {
            console.log("DATA", data);
        }
    });
});
```

I am receiving 200 status from server but nothing happens. The security authentication mechanism is not reacting at all. And success method in ajax is not invoking. I don't know why. I was searching over the Internet a lot but there is almost no information about json authentication in Symfony. There is only a brief description on Symfony docs.

Comment: Did you add `username_path: security.credentials.login` and                `password_path: security.credentials.password` to your `security.yaml` in key `json_login` (like the documentation advises)?

Comment: Hey. As you can see from my AJAX request I am sending a JSON in the simplest format:

`{"username": "dunglas", "password": "MyPassword"}`
so there is no need to specify a `username_path` and `password_path`

Quote from documentation:

If the JSON document has a different structure, you can specify the path to access the username and password properties using the `username_path` and `password_path` keys (they default respectively to username and password).

Comment: Have you found a solution on this? Maybe the Problem is the not empty controller, as this doc states explicitly that the controller should be empty http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/json_login_setup.html

I am having the same problem right now and dont know how to continue.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. You getting a proper response because your controller is returning a valid object. The controller should not be called at all, but intercepted by the security system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to identify the issue. The interception only happens if the request header is set to `Content-Type: application/json`:

Try this in your console:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8000/login_check -d '{"username":"philipp","password":"test"}'
```

In your case, this should solve the problem:

```
$('#login-submit').click(function() {
    let username = $('#username').val();
    let password = $('#password').val();
    let data = JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password});
    $.ajax({
        url: '/login',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (data, status) {
            console.log("DATA", data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you handle the remember me section? Is it handled as well?

Comment: This not working with `fetch`or `axios` libraries using modern javascript :( there is any help ?

Comment: When you logged in via AJAX how can you stay logged in? In my case in log in successfuly  from localhost-1 to localhost-2. When i get content via $.get(url) then i get a 401 again. CORS is enabled with NelmioCorsBundle.

Comment: Hi @KhalidAhmada, since both libraries can customize the request header as in the example above, the authentication should work. Please check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) for `fetch` and [this](https://github.com/axios/axios)  for `axios`.

Comment: Hi @Daviz, it depends on which API type you want to implement. A REST API e.g. is stateless and can not distinguish whether a user is online or offline. The authorization credentials need to send with every request. But you can use the login function to generate user specific [JWT token](https://jwt.io/). This token can be time limited and will be used for all further api requests.